# Is developing Silverlight free, and will it stay that way?

Tags: silverlight

As far as I can tell developing for Silverlight is free as long as you already have Visual Studio 2008. Does anyone know if MS has any plans to change that?

Comment: It's like asking: I can see that Asp.net is free... Will it stay that way? OF COURSE it will. It's in the best interest of MS to get a substantial market share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anything, they will try to make it easier and cheaper.  One recent program is called WebSiteSpark... which gives away all of the Microsoft Web Dev tools.  This is because of increased competition between Microsoft and competing technologies such as those provided by Adobe.

Answer (score 4):

You can develop Silverlight applications using [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/), which is free.

---

And I don't think Microsoft has plans changing that, because that would mean they get a lot less new Silverlight developers, and it would take longer for Silverlight to catch up to Flash.

Comment: You're right, Reshure! 

Developing Silverlight applications costs the same as creating HTML applications. Some of the tools the developer choose to use may costs money, but developing applications is totally costless.

Besides that I actually think that VWD Express is a very cool tool and is amazed that MS ship it for free.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight framework itself is a [free download](http://www.microsoft.com/Silverlight/Install.aspx) from Microsoft. What exactly do you mean, when you say "developing for Silverlight is free"?

Comment: Meaning, will I have to buy anything down the road to continue to use it. For example. WPF can be used in VS2008 but to really make good use of it, you need to but Expression Blend.

Comment: Since we are talking about Microsoft, nothing comes for free. Not even the 'redistributable' frameworks; because eventually we pay for it some way or the other(in form of IDE, compilers, etc) while we develop solutions using Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

And if Visual Studio isn't your cup of tea, there's always [Eclipse Tools for Silverlight](http://www.eclipse4sl.org/) which is also free.